# How to convert 2020-08-17 02:18:34+0000 to Oracle DATE type

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have "2020-08-17 02:18:34+0000" as CSV string and want to insert it to oracle table column having DATE type. I am loading table through JDBC batch code. I tried following

```
TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (TO_TIMESTAMP ('2020-08-17 02:18:34+0000', 'RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

But it did not work. Please help. Thank you.

Edit
Error Message:
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: "did not work" is not found in any error message.  Help us to help you. Don't make us guess what the error message was.

Comment: In java you can parse it with `LocalDate.parse` (the one that accepts a `DateTimeFormatter` as a second input). Then the `toString` method will return a date in a format that should be compatible with an sql date (i.e. `YYYY-mm-dd`)

Comment: You have a ***logical*** problem here, before going to "code". What you have is not a timestamp. it is a timestamp **with time zone**. If you ignore the time zone, you are losing information. Will **all** your inputs be in the same time zone, +0000, meaning UTC (GMT)? If not, you are **definitely** losing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store a timestamp as a DATE - you will lose context. The +0000 at the end of your string, does that represent UTC timezone, as in +/- '0 hours'?

If you have some entries that are more than +0, then stripping that information off will change the context. 3PM in Ireland isn't 3PM in New York City. With DATES you lose all that context, do you need to translate those time differences?

```
select cast(to_timestamp('2020-08-17 02:18:34+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS+FF') as date) dates from dual;
```

If you want to treat the +0000 as throwaway text to your date format model,  you can also use

```
select to_date('2020-08-17 02:18:34+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS"+0000"') dates from dual;
```

Comment: err... no. The mask should be `'...MI:SSTZHTZR'`. The "plus" sign is not a separator, it is an algebraic sign (part of TZH); and FF is for fractional seconds, which are not present in the OP's input. Your format model interprets +0000 as the fractional seconds instead of the time zone hour and minute; definitely wrong despite the OP thinking it's correct.

Comment: Sorry - I meant `TZHTZM`. Now: perhaps the lack of colon threw you (although military time technically doesn't use a colon, so this is not "unusual"); but the + sign as decimal separator? Ever?

Comment: i attempted to withdraw my answer, but it's already been accepted by the OP, is there a god priv to un-accept an answer?

Comment: The alternative is to edit the answer to make it right :-) The simplest solution, in my opinion - assuming ALL dates have the time zone +0000 - is to treat that as boilerplate text (shown in the format model in double-quotes), and to use TO_DATE directly. The bigger issue, though - see my comment under the OP's question - is a logical one. The input is timestamp with time zone. Saving as DATE will lose information.

Comment: right, are they ok with losing the tz? do they realize the difference between ts with tz and date?

Comment: @mathguy i've tried, let me know if we're closer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228171/discussion-between-mathguy-and-thatjeffsmith).

Answer (score 0):

```
TO_TIMESTAMP ('2020-08-17 02:18:34+0000', 'RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

your description 'RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' does not match the character string representation of the timestamp.  You have to account for the '+0000'

Also, please note that the RR format mask was a band-aid to buy some time in dealing with the Y2k bug.  That was over twenty years ago.  Long past time to drop it and use YYYY.